# Linux update error - googlechrome list error

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get this error:

> ```
> W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
> ```

I tried the solution offered in [How To Fix The (Annoying) ‘Failed to Fetch’ Chrome apt Error](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu).

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` file now?

Comment: **deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main** is the content of the file